# Flowable.concatArray not working

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

I am trying to implement [this](https://medium.com/@rikvanv/android-repository-pattern-using-room-retrofit2-and-rxjava2-b48aedd173c) approach to Repository pattern using Rx & Room. I have an api retrieving categories:

```
interface CategoryApi {
    @GET("/categorytags")
    fun getCategories(): Single<List<CategoryTagHolder>>
}
```

This is my Repository:

```
class CategoryRepositoryImpl(private val categoryDao: CategoryDao,
                             private val categoryApi: CategoryApi,
                             private val scheduleProvider: SchedulerProvider, loginRepository: LoginRepository) : AuthRepository(loginRepository), CategoryRepository {


    override fun getCategories(): Flowable<List<Category>> {
        return Flowable.concatArray(
                categoryDao.getCategories().doOnNext {
                    Timber.w("Retrieving Categories from Local DB!")
                },
                getCategoriesFromRemote().doOnNext {
                    Timber.w("Retrieving Categories from API!")
                }
    }

private fun getCategoriesFromRemote() =
            fromFlowable(categoryApi.getCategories().toFlowable())
            .flatMap {
                if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
                    Flowable.just(it[0].categories)
                } else {
                    Flowable.just(listOf())
                }
            }
            .doOnNext {
                saveCategoriesInDb(it)
            }
}
```

And this is my DAO:

```
@Dao
interface CategoryDao {
    @Query("select * from category")
    fun getCategories(): Flowable<List<Category>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun saveAllCategories(categories: List<Category>)

}
```

No matter how I do it, I always get an empty list cause on init my DB is empty! On the logs, only `"Retrieving Categories from Local DB!"` is shown. If I swap the local and remote call, then both log lines are shown, but this defeats the purpose of this approach.

What might I be doing wrong?

This is the viewmodel:

```
 fun getFilters() {
        categoryRepository.getCategories()
                .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
                .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
                .subscribeBy(onNext = {
                    Timber.e("Got cat list $it")
                    categories.value = Result.success(it)
                },
                        onError = {
                            Timber.e("ERROR ${it.message}")
                        }).addTo(disposables)
    }
```

No error is displayed.

Comment: Android databases usually never complete a Flowable of their data so concatArray can't switch to the next source. Either use Single-based APIs, take(1) or timeout-based continuation.

Comment: then the blog post I linked to is wrong?

Comment: The blog author likely hasn't tried its own solution or it was derived something different where the endless source was not an issue.